# Cómo utilizar una instancia de mysql corriendo en en un contenedor de Docker

Tags: docker

Necesito conectarme a la instancia de mysql que está corriendo en un contenedor de docker, el docker ps muestra lo siguiente:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
b6b01206d80a        erp-docker          "docker-php-entrypoi…"   2 hours ago         Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   erp-docker
b13459e144f7        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp          erp-db
```

Luego debo instalar una sql con la base de datos.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: Conéctate al puerto que estás exponiendo. Ya probaste usar workbench o cualquier otro cliente para conectarte al 3306 en esa máquina?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docker exec -it  erp-db /bin/bash

Explication:

comando: docker exec -it -> esto ejecuta un contenedor (modo interactivo)

nombre contenedor: erp-db

shell: /bin/bash | sh | zsh el que prefieras

Comment: Esto es para correr bash dentro del contenedor. Será eso lo que necesita el OP?

Comment: ok me funcionó muchas gracias

Comment: me alegro @user2820116, puedes puntuar la respuesta como correcta y darle un positivo para que otros usuarios se beneficien